# Expressing achievements with present perfect

Tags: perfect-constructions

"She has recently dyed her hair blue."

Did we use the present perfect simple to express an achievement or a finished action in the past with a result in the present??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the present perfect tense shows that the completed action has a result in the present.
In this case, we could have something like:

> *She has recently dyed her hair blue. Now she's going to the party.*